# How to get Object tag having its position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components, gameobject

I'm new to Unity and one problem is stealing too much time from me that it should.

Anyway, I'm trying to get an object tag from a scene while having X and Z position of it. Specifying, I want to get inputs for neural network by getting game object tags surrounding my bot. Is there a function like `GetComponent<>()` or something that will take x,z and return tag?

And another question, I manually put `emptyObject` in every void space so I can get something in return. Would there be a problem if I delete these 'void blocks' and try to check something in that specific x, z position?

[image]

Comment: Not that I know of but you can create a "trigger" that will add objects to his detected area, and then you can check those objects for tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for every Object in the scene with the `Transform` then look search for the ones with the x and z positions and return the tag. The `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` and `GameObject.FindObjectsOfType` functions can do this but for the sake of performance, use `Scene.GetRootGameObjects` to get all the root Objects and the loop thorugh the children from each Root Object with `GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>` and check if the x and z position match.

Use them because they don't return array but just fills a List.

*Finding all the Objects in the Scene*:

```
private List<GameObject> rootGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
private List<Transform> childObjs = new List<Transform>();

private void GetAllRootObject()
{
    Scene activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    activeScene.GetRootGameObjects(rootGameObjects);
}

private void GetAllChildObjs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rootGameObjects.Count; ++i)
    {
        GameObject obj = rootGameObjects[i];

        //Get all child components attached to this GameObject
        obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true, childObjs);
    }
}
```

*Finding object tag with x,z position*:

```
bool xzEquals(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2)
{
    return (Mathf.Approximately(pos1.x, pos2.x)
        && Mathf.Approximately(pos1.z, pos2.z));
}

string GetTagFromPos(float x, float z)
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

    rootGameObjects.Clear();
    childObjs.Clear();

    GetAllRootObject();
    GetAllChildObjs();

    //Loop through all Objects
    for (int i = 0; i < childObjs.Count; i++)
        //check  if x and z matches then return tag
        if (xzEquals(childObjs[i].position, pos))
            return childObjs[i].tag;

    return null;
}

GameObject GetObjectFromPos(float x, float z)
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

    rootGameObjects.Clear();
    childObjs.Clear();

    GetAllRootObject();
    GetAllChildObjs();

    //Loop through all Objects
    for (int i = 0; i < childObjs.Count; i++)
        //check  if x and z matches then return the Object
        if (xzEquals(childObjs[i].position, pos))
            return childObjs[i].gameObject;

    return null;
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
//Get tag from x, z pos
Debug.Log(GetTagFromPos(1, 2));
//Get object from x, z pos
Debug.Log(GetObjectFromPos(1, 2));
```

You can also manually put the Objects you want to search to the List if you want to save some time in the loop.

Comment: I think, it's probably better to do a raycast at the specific position. I suppose that this will be run rather frequently. Or possibly reduce the number of get all object calls to be done only when there is a change to it (otherwise once per level is probably enough). In this case, you can build a look up table.

Comment: I don't know if raycast would do it because OP did not explain what this is used for, why he/she is wants this or how often this is called but just asked how to convert position to an object tag.So, I tried to answer what's in the title assuming it could be any object in the scene